# How to convert PSD to HTML, Bootstrap (tricks)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, psd

I have a PSD file where I have the following line:

```
width: 4px
```

However, when I add a border like this:

```
border: 4px solid #000
```

my browser shows it with an 8px width.

Does my border have it's own paddings?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on [jsfiddle?](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I think I can't , because I use Bootstrap, and as I know jsfiddle doesn't support it

Comment: Hmm, do you mean the entire element grows 8px, or a single border is being rendered 8px thick?  If it's the first case, this is because borders count towards the entire width of an element ([see here](https://jsfiddle.net/zoht0zxq/)).

Comment: @May It does, but easier to create a [**bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/new#)

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/PZLFHfudBk

Comment: Btw, jsFiddle does support Bootstrap, you just need to import it into your resources. But `Bootply` works fine for this as well, just a different toolset between the two. **Also**, `bootstrap` tag isn't needed, since it has no relation to `twitter-bootstrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it adds a border around the div. So there's 4px on top, and 4px on bottom. If you change it to border-top, or border-bottom, it will just be 4px.

Comment: aaaa yeeeessss !!! thanks a lot ;)